Lottie on Expo (Web) impossible to run
I have followed the simple instructions here:
https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/lottie/
But when I try to run the app this is the error i get:
expo Uncaught Error: lottie-react-native: The module @lottiefiles/react-lottie-player is missing.

I tried to install everything missing but keeps me telling that the repo doesn't exist:
#npx expo install @lottiefiles/react-lottie-player
npm ERR! command git --no-replace-objects ls-remote ssh://git@github.com/lottiefiles/react-lottie-player.git
npm ERR! ERROR: Repository not found.

Is a problem with the repo right?
Can i install it manually?

It's very strange but I have found a solution that is working very well.
On the web I'm using react-lottie and not lottie-react-native as stated on the official documentation.
I hope that this solution will be useful for someone that is in the same situation I was.
